# Casting in UE4 to derived class

Tags: c++, unreal, unreal-4

I’m stuck in understanding of usable actors from survivable c++ example.
I have `return Cast<AUsableItem>(Hit.GetActor());`.
I have class `AUsableItem`. And I have another class `AUsableWeapon` inherited from `AUsableItem`.

I have function `Use()` in both classes, so basically in the end it looks like `Cast<AUsableItem>(Hit.GetActor())->Use()`. `Hit.GetActor()` returns instance of `AUsableWeapon`. And when i do that `->Use()` call, it goes into `AUsableWeapon` even though it was casted to `AUsableItem`. Problem is - I cant understand how exactly after casting to `AUsableWeapon` I get `Use()` called from `AUsableWeapon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the whole point of inheritance, that the method of the derived class is called.
When `AUsableWeapon` redefines a method from its base class then it also has to ensure that a caller never has to worry about which method is called.

To do that, you usually use `Super::Use()` from inside your `AUsableWeapon::Use()` method, so it calls the method from the parent class and then does something in addition to that.

Comment: Thing is - i expected `Cast` to return me instance of `AUsableItem` instead of `AUsableWeapon`

Comment: I don't think that the cast actually changes the underlying object - all it does is to tell the compiler that you are allowed to call certain methods on an object. Which method is called then depends on the actual class of the object/which method were overriden etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Use` function must be declared as virtual. As the instance is of type `AUsableWeapon` virtual will ensure that AUsableWeapon's version of the `Use` function is always called even if it is casted to a base class pointer type.

Either make it non-virtual by removing the keyword or rename the function in both classes to something else like `UseItem` and `UseWeapon`.